# keyboardDidShowNotification and keyboardWillShowNotification are triggered after taping on a keyboard key

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, notificationcenter

This is the code for the whole app. Just add a `UITextField` on the storyboard and tap on it. You will print "AAAA". Then tap on any key on the keyboard. It will print"AAAA" again.

Why is UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification notification triggered 2nd time in this situation? How can I prevent that?

Same behaviour for keyboardWillShowNotification :(

**CODE:**

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        addKeyboardObservers(to: .default)
    }

    func addKeyboardObservers(to notificationCenter: NotificationCenter) {
          notificationCenter.addObserver(
              forName: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification,
              object: nil,
              queue: OperationQueue.main,
              using: { _ in
                    print("AAAA")
              }
          )
    }
}
```

same for code from Harish:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
          self,
          selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown),
          name: UIWindow.keyboardDidShowNotification,
          object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWasShown(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        print("AAA")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use below?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      self,
      selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown),
      name: UIWindow.keyboardDidShowNotification,
      object: nil)
  }

  @objc func keyboardWasShown(_ notification: NSNotification) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet is as good as mine :) Unfortunately both reproduce the same error (I've tried to edit your comment instead of my post. Please delete my edit if able)